# How to give floats/figures titles?

Tags: floats, captions

Below is an excerpt from my thesis, showing a figure with a caption.

I'd like to give the figure a title too, that is, a few words written above the figure.

Can I do that in latex? If so, how?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./graphics/chapter6/mouse.pdf}
\caption{Blablabla}
\label{fig:length_eight_mouse}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Did you create the plot with `matplotlib`? Then you could also add a title there, though the font wouldn't match the document font.

Comment: Yes, that's why I did not include one there. The fonts did not match and it all became so tacky.

Comment: The fonts don't match on your axis scales either (and presumably your axis labels) - your are labelling your axes I assume?  I've just been testing an alternative approach for my thesis - see my answer below.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `{figure}` environment isn't limited to contain only figures etc. You can add anything so just type in your title above the figure.

[image: manually]

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \textbf{Your title}\par\medskip
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
    \caption{Your caption}
\end{figure}
```

You can define a new command like `\figuretitle` to make the formatting and spacing consistent.

```
\newcommand*{\figuretitle}[1]{%
    {\centering%   <--------  will only affect the title because of the grouping (by the
    \textbf{#1}%              braces before \centering and behind \medskip). If you remove
    \par\medskip}%            these braces the whole body of a {figure} env will be centered.
}
```

Looks the same as above, but can be used as

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \figuretitle{Your title}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
    \caption{Your caption}
\end{figure}
```

Or you can use the `\caption` above the figure. In this case you may use the `caption` package to adjust the spacing.

[image: caption above]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
    position=above,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{Your caption}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{example-image}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ps. for other newbs: \newcommands should be inserted in your config-file to get it to work in every chapter. In my case this is classicthesis-config.tex.

Comment: This is not wrong but neither correct ;-) You can place the definition anywhere in sour document and use it frome there on. It is common sense to put definition in the preamble, i.e. the part before `\begin{document}, and the definition is scoped by a group, e.g. An environment ...

Comment: Thanks. Right. Classicthesis has even included a space in the preamble for this. Ps. I guess the \centering does not need to be included when you use the \figuretitle?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: Yes the `\centering` is kind of redundant in this case, but I used a group, i.e. a pair of braces `{}`, so `\centering` will only affect the title and not the image. If you want to center all images I’d do it globally, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6033/4918.

Answer (score 4):

You could try making the `matplotlib` text look like LaTeX:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# This is the first important line:
from matplotlib import rcParams

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], 
         [2, 4, 6, 8])

# These are the second and third important lines:
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')

# Change the fontsize to match your document.
plt.xlabel("This is a cool label.", fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel("This is another cool label.", fontsize=12)
plt.savefig("image.pdf", dpi=200)
```

[image: LaTeX Style Fonts from matplotlib!]

Comment: I found these two web pages very useful to produce the plots of my thesis with Matplotlib:
http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/LaTeX_Examples
and
http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/UsingTex .
However I would not do it again; instead I would let LaTeX produce the plots itself (see ticz package for instance). Advantages: (1) actually looks like LaTeX; (2) fix typos, resize and restyle without having to rerun your 4-years-old python code and (3) no need to deal with Matplotlib's maddening API and documentation.

Comment: Just want to add for anyone considering this, `matplotlib` is very good for making titles but if you need different colours in your title (I need coloured numbers that correspond to colours in my plot), do not use `matplotlib`. It is quite painful and inconsistent, hence why I am here to do in within latex.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method is to output from Matplotlib as .svg, with or without a title then read in to Inkscape.  You can save from Inkscape as .pdf+.tex (or .eps+.tex I think), where the .pdf(.eps) contains the graphics, and the .tex overlays the text, in your current document font.  All this can be done from the command line - Inkscape supports that.

A couple of links:

[Setting up matplotlib to output text as text](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/353/)

[Adjusting sizing of figure and text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113282/text-size-in-inkscape)

Answer (score 0):

I used the `\tabular`-environment.

This is useful for multiple figures with different (centered) titles especially.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
        \textbf{\underline{Title One}} & \textbf{\underline{Title Two}} \\
        \includegraphics{picture1.png} & \includegraphics{picture2.png}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Caption Zero}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet compilable and add an screenshot of your result to your answer?