# Improve the appearance of SAS output in overleaf

Tags: graphics

This is honestly a part of my project that I have been dreading. I am wondering how to improve the appearance of my SAS output in my latex document because right now . . . it's not amazing. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=7cm]{bubble.png}
\end{document}
```

Have a look:

[image]

Edit: 4/28

@NicolaTalbot made the line width statement evident to me:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\title{\LARGE \bf ECON 425 Term Paper}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{bubble.png}

\end{document}
```

This is cool, but the image still doesn't appear centered within the column which is a bit disorienting. Does anyone know how to situate the figure more in the center?

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: **The question is very broad un unclear to me at the moment.** You did not even post some code. By the way, I do *not* find the result very ugly. I like the graph :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner thanks! I didn't post any code, because there really wasn't much. But I will edit the post and add some code. And my question really is just for people who have tried this before who may have some tips or tricks about the best way to do this. For example, I can barely read the title--maybe it would be better to type up the title rather than have it in the SAS output? Not sure.

Comment: You can control the title-size with font-size commands (\large , Large, & so on), if I understand what you say...; If you are importing an image, just get rid of the title and add it using latex.

Comment: @santimirandarp but the title is in the .png image--so that probably can't be adjusted

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128185/how-to-give-floats-figures-titles

Comment: I suggest that you include a list in the question. The list could state some kind of "degree of freedom" (what can be changed).

Comment: there is no usable code in the code fragment you posted (end document but no begin document for example but looking at your image it looks like your graphic is too wide for the column and also son't do `\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=7cm]{bubble.png}` just specify one of width or height otherwise you will distort the image

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the begin document. And thanks for the advice--ill change that now.

Comment: It's probably simpler to set the width relative to the current line width. For example `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{bubble.png}` or `\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{bubble.png}`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thanks for that code. I prefer that over guessing. I will edit the original post for a follow-up question

Comment: In your second MWE the initial paragraph indent is shifting the figure over to the right slightly. If it's inside a `figure` environment it should be sufficient to do something like `\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics[...]{...}\caption{}...\end{figure}`. Outside of a `figure` environment you need something like `{\centering\includegraphics[...]{...}\par}` (the `\par` before the closing brace is important). Or just `\noindent\includegraphics[...]{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarise the comments:

Use `\linewidth` or fractions of `\linewidth` to adjust the width. It's easier than trying to guess the correct length. Examples:

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image}
```

In the default justified text, you need to take the paragraph indentation into account. This can be suppressed with `\noindent` at the start of the paragraph. Alternatively, if you use `\centering`, `\flushleft` or `\flushright`, the paragraph indent is change to 0pt. For example:

```
{\centering
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
 \par
}
```

The `\par` is important and needs to go before the scope ends. The `figure` environment automatically scopes the contents so the braces aren't needed there.

In the example below, the first image is the scaled to the width of the line, but the paragraph indent causes it to shift over the edge of the column.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]%dummy text

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\lipsum[11]%dummy text

\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

\lipsum[13]%dummy text

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
 \caption{An Example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]