# Inkscape text size, change of reference text

Tags: fontsize, inkscape

I have a question similar to [Text size in inkscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113282/text-size-in-inkscape).

I use inkscape to generate my figure for latex, 
that are resized with

```
\def\svgwidth
```

while text size remains the same,
there is a way to scale all the text (and maintaining the relative differences between normal size, `\tiny` size, etc.) in a single figure? e.g.

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\figsize}
    \def\svgtextsize{\textsize}%I would like to have it!
    \includesvg{myfigure}
    \caption{...}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

this would allow to shrink the character size by the same amount in all the figures, independently by the scaling of each figures, as i was doing with the psfrag.

Comment: Export in TikZ: then you can do whatever trickery you like.

Comment: I agree with Claudio. However, you can put the font size command along with `\centering` say, `\small\centering`. Use `\fontsize` command too if you want. Is that OK for you?

Comment: both fontsize (e.g. `\fontsize{1cm}{1em}`) and font size commands (`\small`) work **so long** there are no extra specification of sizes in the svg text. In my case there is a `\small my small text` inside the picture as well, that is not scaled by any command