# SVG from Inkscape to LaTeX ruins typesetting

Tags: svg, inkscape, convert

I would like to use the `.pdf_tex` option for my SVG images exported from Inkscape because it's an amazing feature but it doesn't work as intended.

What I do:

1. Export image from Inkscape
2. Integrate into TeX by

   ```
   \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
       \input{N1N2N3.pdf_tex}
   \end{figure}
   ```
3. Compile

Result:

In the PDF

[image]

My original SVG:

[image]

So thats not what I expected.
Can you help me to get it tidy and neat?

So I fixed it partly by using

```
\begin{center}
\resizebox{2in}{!}{\input{inkscapeout.pdf_tex}}
\end{center}
```

to scale text and image together but I still got a problem with the xlabel of the graph because the numbers are moved into the graph and also the legend is moved a little upward.

New result

[image]

I uploaded my original **svg-file** here

https://owncloud.tu-berlin.de/index.php/s/8pRPwotDkiS0C5K

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113282/text-size-in-inkscape

Comment: Thank you for your advice although it doesn't solve my problem entirely.

Comment: The pdf is included a bit too far down, as you have noticed. Workaround: change the corresponding line in the pdf_tex file to `\put(0,0.007){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{N1N2N3.pdf}}%` (around line 50). However, if you are not using any LaTeX code in your graphs, maybe exporting to eps is easier?

Comment: Maybe you are right, it's just a nice feature that text and graph use the same font. But still thx for the workaround and if somebody finds a non-workaround solution I would greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: (The url to your `svg` document is dead. Could you provide a valid link?)

Comment: One main reason to use this feature is that text should be consistent with the font type and font **size** of the rest of the document.  So, if you use this feature, it is up to you take care that the final image size is consistent with that font size ...  and not the opposite. The "scalable" nature of Inkscape do not  favor take care of real size of the SVG graph and their labels, but this  is best approach, i.e, ensure that the original plot is made according to its final size, avoiding any scaling, and that text in Inkscape is really of similar dimensions to the TeX font.

Comment: `\includesvg` apparently treats text in your figure independently, so that it is rendered by LATEX by default. Probably the best way to solve this is to change the option `inkscapelatex` to false. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498352/194783).

Comment: Note that this will also use the font style of the figure and not of the document, which might be an unwanted side effect.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting a smaller font size should probably improve the result. Unfortunately the external link to the .svg file is death, so I can just guess a value

```
\begin{figure}
    \fontsize{6pt}{7pt}\selectfont
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \input{N1N2N3.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

Alternatively you could increase the font size in the original .svg (or whatever program you used to produce the graph).