# How to scale text in SVG

Tags: svg, inkscape

I use Inkscape to convert an SVG to pdf latex, after the conversion I want to scale the image so it matches the second image. But the text does not scale accordingly to the boxes. I use the following code to render the first image. Does anyone know how I can scale the boxes and the text, so it matches the second image?

```
\usepackage{svg}


\begin{figure}[ht] 
    \centering 
    \includesvg[width=0.7\textwidth]{someimage} 
    \caption{foo} 
    \label{bar} 
\end{figure}
```

[image: Wrongly Scaled image]

[image: Image should scale to this]

Comment: Try with a smaller font size within the figure environment,  for example `\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont`

Comment: What happens if you put the unscaled `\includegraphics` inside a `\scalebox`?

Comment: \fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont works ! thanks.

Comment: Usually, often I need maintain not only the font size, but also the font style of the SVG file.  It is not clear in your question if that is also your aim in this case. If so, save the graphic as PDF without check PDF+LaTeX. Safer and simpler.

Comment: @samcarter thanks for the tip. It would be Nice if you would provide the answer 

Comment: I always take the approach @Fran mentions, and throughly recommend it. The amount of work involved in getting a complex figure to integrate well with the document using pdf+latex is huge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few different possibilities:

- `\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont` (or whatever size is appropriate) to use a smaller font size.
- use the same font size as in your document already during the design process in inkscape
- or, as Harald Hanche-Olsen pointed out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390804/how-to-scale-text-in-svg?noredirect=1#comment970461_390804) include the graphic with a larger size and scale it down using `\scalebox` or similar tools.

Comment: Another option would be to use `\includesvg[pretex=\small,<other params>]{<svgfile>}` or any other font size switch than `\small` fulfilling your needs

Comment: Would you be able to give an example usage of `\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont`? 
I just tried `\includesvg[\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont,width=0.25\textwidth]{example.svg}` but that didn't work (and doesn't feel right...)

Comment: Got it!: [anywhere in the figure environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390804/how-to-scale-text-in-svg/391003#comment970457_390804) - extra info [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_adjust_the_font_size%3F#Example:_using_\fontsize_and_\selectfont)

Answer (score 32):

I am adding this because the accepted answer does not mention this solution, which is much cleaner.

`\includesvg` treats whatever text in your figure independently by default.

The cleanest way to scale your text with your figure is to set the `inkscapelatex` parameter to `false`. [This document](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/svg/svg.pdf) explains this as follows:

> If option `inkscapelatex=true` is set, the output is split into a seperate
> PDF/EPS/PS file (see optioninkscapeformat) and a corresponding LATEX
> file. This is the default setting. Setting `inkscapelatex=false` will
> result in a single PDF/EPS/PS file, where any contained text won’t be
> rendered by LATEX.

Therefore, `\includesvg[inkscapelatex=false,<other params>]{svgfile}` is what you are looking for.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution.

Comment: But that means LaTeX's font will not be used for the text, mathematical expressions will not be typeset by LaTeX, and so on. There is a case for still rendering text in LaTeX AND being able to scale the image and the text at the same time.

Comment: Another option would be to use `\includesvg[pretex=\small,<other params>]{<svgfile>}` or any other font size switch than `\small` fulfilling your need

Answer (score 4):

To add to the answer of cPickle (because I'm not allowed to comment yet):

You can also set the option inkscapelatex=false globally by using `\svgsetup` after importing the svg package:

```
\usepackage{svg}
\svgsetup{inkscapelatex=false}
```