# LaTeX changing svg text font

Tags: fonts, input, svg, inkscape

I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2107) to use a svg image in my LaTeX document, but LaTeX changes the font I used when I created the image. How can I keep the "original" I set in Inkscape?

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you, it works exactly as I want. Sorry for the foolish question but I am quite new to LaTeX. Just another thing: when I run the command without `--export-latex` I get  a warning: `(inkscape:9326): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:32:30.778: Impossibile trovare il motore del tema in module_path: «hcengine»,`, which in English means something like "couldn't find the theme engine in module_path «hcengine»,". Is it a problem?

Comment: I doubt it; the warning states that it cannot find the hcengine (one of the GTK/Gnome themes for high contrast). You can fix it by installing gtk-engines in your linux distribution, but it shouldn't have an effect on the pdf export of inkscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the same font as the main document, you should just export the SVG file directly as a PDF (without the `--export-latex` option) and `\includegraphics` the PDF file. (The linked answer in your original question is specifically about how to export the graphics part into a PDF file and the text part separately into a TeX file that can be treated using LaTeX to produce a consistent font choice.)

*(Above answer copied from [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507042/latex-changing-svg-text-font?noredirect=1#comment1281209_507042))*

Answer (score 7):

`\includesvg` apparently treats text in your figure independently, so that it is rendered by LATEX by default.

Probably the best way to solve this is to change the option `inkscapelatex` to false. Quote from the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/svg/svg.pdf):

> If option `inkscapelatex=true` is set, the output is split into a seperate PDF/EPS/PS file (see optioninkscapeformat) and a corresponding LATEX file. This is the default setting. Setting `inkscapelatex=false` will result in a single PDF/EPS/PS file, where any contained text won’t be rendered by LATEX.

Example: `\includesvg[inkscapelatex=false,<other params>]{svgfile}`.

(Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498352/194783)