# Putting figures over other figures/images

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, fontsize, scaling

I want to put 4 diagrams on top of a map, so that the fontsize of the text in the diagram can be the same as in the rest of the text. The entire page is size A4.

Currently, I'm implementing the diagrams as PDF-Exports from separate projects and put them as graphic (scaled) ontop of the map.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe,tikz}\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure} \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[      
        every node/.style={anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt},
        x=1mm, y=1mm,
      ]   
     \node (fig1) at (-10,125)
       {\includegraphics[scale=2]{Bilder/MAP_DE.pdf}};
     \node (fig2) at (45,120)
       {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Bilder/AnnProdDM.pdf}};  
     \node (fig3) at (20,60)
       {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Bilder/AnnProdKO.pdf}};  
     \node (fig4) at (75,60)
       {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Bilder/AnnProdIK.pdf}};  
     \node (fig5) at (60,5)
       {\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Bilder/AnnProdLB.pdf}};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Current output]

Is there a simple way to put all of them in the same project and then putting the figures on top of each other, so that the font size can be the same as in the text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Is the text embedded in the included PDFs? If so, LaTeX has no control over their size, except the scaling done to the entire included PDF. Of course, you could make them bigger by changing the scale, and have them overlap as much as you want, but I don't see how that isn't going to create other problems. To change just the text size, you'd likely need to go back to your other project and change your export method; see, e.g., [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390804/how-to-scale-text-in-svg) for svgs.

Comment: While you can't put a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture, you can position entire scopes relative to each other.  You can also create saveboxes and replace `\includegraphics` with `\scalebox{1}{\usebox\foo}` (where \foo is the savebox name).

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't just put whatever code generated your diagram PDFs directly inside the nodes. You might need to drop the scaling factor, then, and do scaling within the inner code directly. But this should apply all font settings from the outer scope inside! Plus, this is future proof, if you ever want to change font size/style later on.