# Resize text in SVG without cramming?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, overleaf, text, svg

I imported an `.svg` image inside my document using the `svg` package. Since the image is too big, I used `\resizebox{}{}{}` to scale down both the image and its inside text at once. But I want the image's text to match the document's. So I used `\fontsize{}{}` to adjust it to match the size. But the problem is, the image's text gets too crammed and unreadable. How can I fix this?

My code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont
\resizebox{6in}{!}{\includesvg{images/ECG-EEG Coherence}}
\end{figure}
```

Original `.svg` image:
[image]
After compiling it looks like this:
[image]

**How can I modify my code to get the image look as I wanted?**

Comment: you would neeed to edit the svg to reposition the text, there is no general fix, basically you need to recreate a better diagram.

Comment: Yeah, but it's kinda sad that LaTeX being known for its versatility, can't be able to achieve this.

Comment: How could anyone, in any system, fix a bad image and generate a better image with no information about the source? The problem here is not latex, it is simply your question has no information that would allow anyone to answer.

Comment: all you need to do is move your axis labels further out which is probably a simple edit to the svg but editing unseen code is hard

Comment: The image was produced in MATLAB, so we have no control over adjusting the spacing between the axes labels.

Comment: as I say you could edit the svg, or in matlab you could control the plot size so you did not have to shrink it and make the text small.

Comment: Maybe one of the solutions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390804/how-to-scale-text-in-svg would work. Particularly something like `\includesvg[pretex=\tiny]{svgfilename}` seems promising. In any case `\fontsize{20}{20}` as you have now seems much too big.